# Does Windows remove hooks automatically?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook, system

Win32 API allows creating hook into system processes such as mouse hook (WH_MOUSE_LL), a hook is created with `SetWindowsHookExA/W` functions.

The scenario is, a programme has installed a hook into Windows system with a local function; the programme does have a hook uninstall at the end, but, there's a case when the programme crashes and hook uninstall function is not called.

**Does Windows know about dead hooks? and remove them automatically?**

Hooks do pass around messages in a sequence: hook1 --> callnexthook --> hook2 --> callnexthook...

When the hook2 is dead, would it spoil the system?

Comment: _"...Before terminating, an application must call the UnhookWindowsHookEx function to free system resources associated with the hook...."_ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa  Means that even if Windows currently does remove dead hooks you can't rely on that behaviour.

Comment: [Related/Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4478829/10871073)?

Comment: @RichardCritten that's a great find but it doesn't tell you what the consequences are when you can't do that. I suppose it's like undefined behavior, you can't know and hope you never find out.

Comment: hook related to thread. and information about this saved in thread object (in general sense). when thread terminated - if hook still exist on thread - it removed

Comment: Does Windows know about dead hooks? yes (hook is dead after thread, which set it terminared, or if we direct call UnhookWindowsHookEx ) and remove them automatically? - yes, of course. otherwise this is bug in system design and resourse leak

Comment: in details calls on thread exit - `UserThreadCallout(PsW32ThreadCalloutExit) -> xxxDestroyThreadInfo() -> FreeThreadsWindowHooks() -> UnlinkHook + FreeHook`. [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38125642/6401656)